# Android - Is there any callback for when my activity is about to throw an OutOfMemory exception?

Tags: android, memory-management

I have a ViewFlipper in which, in each of its subviews, I put a bitmap on it. The thing is that I am worried that my application (in special, that Activity) will run out of memory and throw an (OutOfMemory) exception.

I thought in capturing the "OutOfMemory" exception, but that would be too late already...

I want to implement some callback method for when my activity is "**about** to run out of memory" (like, it will run out of memory if I allocate 2 or 3 more bitmaps).

Is there any method we can implement so I can free some of those loaded bitmaps inside it? I don't want to free the bitmaps if my application still has plenty of memory to have the bitmaps in memory.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: onLowMemory? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onLowMemory%28%29

Comment: Thanks for replying Willian. I knew that method, but it doesn't seem to be what I want. I want a method that will be called when my application is running out of memory (not the entire Android).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can verify free memory of the system at that point

[How do I discover memory usage of my application in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298208/how-to-discover-memory-usage-of-my-application-in-android)

In android 4.1 New ComponentCallbacks2 constants such as TRIM_MEMORY_RUNNING_LOW and TRIM_MEMORY_RUNNING_CRITICAL provide foreground processes more information about memory state before the system calls onLowMemory().

Comment: This is great information! Thanks vishwa. Answer accepted now.